# implict Declaration of function

Tags: c

Can you help me how to deal with warnings about implicit declarations of function? I often get this warning in my most of my library functions like in `clrscr()`, `delay()` and some user-idefined functions too.

A part of actual code:

```
void login()
{
    int c;
    char username[20];
    char pass[20];
    char chkp;
    char chku;

    clrscr();
    gotoxy(23, 5);
    printf("_____Login Zone___");
    gotoxy(23, 7);

    fp = fopen("record.bin", "rb");

    printf("Enter UserName         :");

    gets(username);

    gotoxy(23, 9);

    printf("Enter PassWord         :");
```

A part of output:

```
form.c: In function 'login':
form.c:38:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clrscr'; did you mean 'clock'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     int y=clrscr();
           ^~~~~~
           clock
form.c:40:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gotoxy' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     gotoxy(23, 5);
     ^~~~~~
form.c: In function 'main':
form.c:190:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'delay' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                 delay(40);
```

Comment: What OS are you using, and which "C Compiler" ?

Comment: i am using Windows and MinGW compiler

Comment: These function are meant to be used only in the ancient `Turbo C` - `Borland C` compilers. Look for alternatives.

Comment: do you mean i have to use other functions?can you please suggest one for clrscr() and delay()

Comment: include `stdlib.h`, try `system("cls")` for `clrscr()`

Comment: As for delay, check out [sleep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep)

Comment: IF compiler shows warning ,then does it mean it will not execute that function ? or it is just for making good coding habits ?

Comment: The compiler sees no prototype of that function, therefore it has not been implemented.

Comment: "A part of actual code" is insufficient; show everything needed for readers to reproduce the problem. Chances are you just don't `#include` the headers for the functions you use. You should also turn on a 'strict' compiler mode such that implicit declarations become errors, because they are no use to anyone.

Comment: Be very careful with study materials from India. Something with the school system there dictates that they must teach all students completely outdated practices, including Turbo C, MS DOS programming, `gets` function and so on. `delay` was a function of the MS DOS API provided by Borland in 1989. If you don't intend to program MS DOS computers from the 1980s, then don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the warning because you forgot to add some include files. But anyway, those functions should be replaced by escape sequences.

To clear the screen, move cursor, change colors and more, you have to use escape sequences. This works for Windows or Linux and many other operating systems.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) explain how to use it. Somewhere near the end of this documentation, you'll find an example using C language.

As you'll see in the example, to enable terminal escape sequences under windows, you have to call `SetConsoleMode` [Windows API function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode). This is not needed nor desirable under Linux so you shall use conditional compilation if you want to make your program cross-platform.

Microsoft Windows supports more escape sequences than what directly explained in the documentation. Refer to [this document](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) for
[more escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). But this time, the list is not completely supported. You'll have to discover by yourself.

I wrote a simple example based on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    printf("\x1B[%d;%dH", y, x);
}

void clrscr(void)
{
    printf("\x1B[2J");
}

DWORD initconsole(void)
{
    // Set output mode to handle virtual terminal sequences
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    DWORD dwMode = 0;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }
    return 0;
}

void login()
{
    char username[20];
    char pass[20];

    clrscr();
    gotoxy(23, 5);
    printf("_____Login Zone___");
    gotoxy(23, 7);
    printf("Enter UserName         :");
    fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
    gotoxy(23, 9);
    printf("Enter PassWord         :");
    fgets(pass, sizeof(pass), stdin);
}

void main(void)
{
    initconsole();
    login();
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider the curses/ncurses library.   It is supported virtually everywhere, and automatically handles different terminal escape requirements.